# How is browser event loop processing macro tasks?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser, event-loop

I watched Jake Archibald's talk about event loop - https://vimeo.com/254947206. Based on the talk my understanding was that event loop will execute as many macro tasks as it can fit in one frame and if there is some long running macro task it will cause frames to be skipped. So my expectation was that any task, running longer then usual frame duration, would cause other tasks to be executed in the next frame. I tested that by creating one button and multiple handlers like this https://codepen.io/jbojcic1/full/qLggVW

I noticed that even though handlerOne is long running (due to calculating computationally intensive fibonacci), handlers 2, 3 and 4 are still executed in the same frame. Only timeoutHandler is being executed in the next frame. Here are the logs I am getting:

```
  animationFrameCallback - 10:4:35:226
  handler one called. fib(40) = 102334155
  handler two called.
  handler three called.
  handler four called.
  animationFrameCallback - 10:4:36:37
  timeout handler called
  animationFrameCallback - 10:4:36:42
```

so the question is why are handlers two, three and four executed within the same frame as handler one?

To make things even more confusing according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Frame_Timing_API,

> A frame represents the amount of work a browser does in one event
>   loop iteration such as processing DOM events, resizing, scrolling,
>   rendering, CSS animations, etc.

and to explain "one event loop iteration" they linked https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#processing-model-8 where it's stated that in one iteration:

- one macro task is processed,
- all micro tasks are processed
- rendering is updated
- ... (there are some other steps too which are
  not important for this)

which doesn't seem to be correct at all.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing a few concepts here.

The "frame" you are measuring in your codepen is the one of the [step 10 - **Update the rendering**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering).
Quoting the specs:

> This specification does not mandate any particular model for selecting rendering opportunities. But for example, if the browser is attempting to achieve a 60Hz refresh rate, then rendering opportunities occur at a maximum of every 60th of a second (about 16.7ms). If the browser finds that a browsing context is not able to sustain this rate, it might drop to a more sustainable 30 rendering opportunities per second for that browsing context, rather than occasionally dropping frames. Similarly, if a browsing context is not visible, the user agent might decide to drop that page to a much slower 4 rendering opportunities per second, or even less.

So it is not sure at which frequency will this "*frame*" fire, but generally it is at 60FPS (most monitors refresh at 60Hz), so in this lapse of time, **a lot** of event loops iterations will normally occur.

Now, requestAnimationFrame is even more special in that it can discard *frames* if the browser thinks it has too much things to perform. So your fibonacci will most probably delay any execution of rAF callbacks until it's done.

---

What the MDN article you linked talks about is a "*frame*" in the realm of the [PerformanceFrameTiming API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceFrameTiming). I must admit directly that I don't have a lot of knowledge about this particular API, and given its very limited browser support, I don't think we should spend too much time on it, except to say that this has nothing to do with a painting frame.

I think the most precise tool we have currently for measuring an EventLoop iteration is the [Messaging API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent).
By creating a self-calling message event loop, we can hook to every EventLoop iterations.

```js
let stopped = false;
let eventloops = 0;
onmessage = e => {
  if(stopped) {
    console.log(`There has been ${eventloops} Event Loops in one anim frame`);
    return;
  }
  eventloops++
  postMessage('', '*');
};
requestAnimationFrame(()=> {
  // start the message loop
  postMessage('', '*');
  // stop in one anim frame
  requestAnimationFrame(()=> stopped = true);
});
```

Let's see how your code behaves at a deeper level:

```js
let done = false;
let started = false;
onmessage = e => {
  if (started) {
    let a = new Date();
    console.log(`new EventLoop - ${a.getHours()}:${a.getMinutes()}:${a.getSeconds()}:${a.getMilliseconds()}`);
  }
  if (done) return;
  postMessage('*', '*');
}

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", handlerOne);
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", handlerTwo);
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", handlerThree);
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", handlerFour);

function handlerOne() {
  started = true;
  setTimeout(timeoutHandler);
  console.log("handler one called. fib(40) = " + fib(40));
}

function handlerTwo() {
  console.log("handler two called.");
}

function handlerThree() {
  console.log("handler three called.");
}

function handlerFour() {
  console.log("handler four called.");
  done = true;
}

function timeoutHandler() {
  console.log("timeout handler called");
}

function fib(x) {
  if (x === 1 || x === 2) return 1
  return fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2);
}
postMessage('*', '*');
```

```html
<button id="button">Click me</button>
```

Ok, so there is actually one *frame* as in *EventLoop iteration* to fire between the event handlers and the setTimeout callback. I like it better.

#### But what about that *"long running frames"* thing we heard about?

I'll guess you are talking about the [*"spin the event loop"*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#spin-the-event-loop) algorithm, which is indeed meant to allow the event loop to not block all the UI in some circumstances.

First, specs only tell the implementers that it is a recommendation to enter this algorithm for long running scripts, it is not a must.

Then, this algorithm is to allow the normal EventLoop processing of events registration and UI updates, but anything related to javascript is simply resumed at the next EventLoop iteration.

So there is actually no way from js to know if we did enter this algorithm.

Even my MessageEvent driven loop can't tell, because the event handler will just get pushed to after we exit this long-running script.

Here is an attempt to put in a more graphical way, at the risk of being technically inacurate:

```
/**
 * ...
 * - handle events
 *    user-click => push([cb1, cb2, cb3]) to call stack
(* - paint if needed (may execute rAF callbacks if any))
 *
 * END OF LOOP
—————————————————————————
 * BEGIN OF LOOP
 *
 * - execute call stack
 *    cb1()
 *      schedule `timeoutHandler`
 *      fib()
 *      ...
 *      ...
 *      ...
 *      ... <-- takes too long => "spin the event loop"
 * [ pause call stack ]
 * - handle events
(* - paint if needed (but do not execute rAF callbacks))
 *
 * END OF LOOP
—————————————————————————
 * BEGIN OF LOOP
 *
 * - execute call stack
 * [ resume call stack ]
 *      (*fib()*)
 *      ...
 *      ...
 *    cb2()
 *    cb3()
 * - handle events
 *   `timeoutHandler` timed out => push to call stack
(* - paint if needed (may execute rAF callbacks if any) )
 *
 * END OF LOOP
—————————————————————————
 * BEGIN OF LOOP
 *
 * - execute call stack
 *   `timeoutHandler`()
 * - handle events
 ...
 */
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. When you say "EventLoop iteration" what exactly are you referring to? Also not sure what did you try to show with second snippet? This is what I am getting there:

```
handler one called. fib(40) = 102334155
handler two called.
handler three called.
handler four called.
new EventLoop - 9:5:13:185
new EventLoop - 9:5:13:187
timeout handler called
```

Comment: Regarding "paint frame" I understand that it won't always be 60 per seconds. Long running macro task will block the main thread causing frame rate to drop but what I don't understand is why, in my example, paint is not done immediately after handler 1 is done? 
I guess it's because it first handles all macrotasks that were in queue at the time when long running task starts to execute?

Comment: @jbojcic "event loop iteration" is one event loop, what the performance frame timing calls a "frame"., which is different than a painting frame (that you do hook to with rAF). The second snippet is just using a better way of controlling how many times the event loop *looped*, since using requestAnimationFrame is unreliable. And it demonstrates that timeout always occurs in a different event loop than all the click callbacks.

Comment: And yes, when the long running callback starts executing, all the other callbacks are already part of the js execution, so even if the browser enters the spin the event loop, they'll be the next things to get executed, in the same event loop than the one the long running did end in.

Comment: @jbojcic I added some walkthrough, in the hope it's clearer to you what happens.

Comment: but if this pausing and rerunning of long tasks would be true, wouldn't that mean that blocking ui would be impossible while it certainly is possible?

Comment: @jbojcic that is the whole point yes, to finally avoid that scripts can block the UI. Once again, all browsers won't enter this "spin the event loop" on the same criteria, Firefox for instance enters in way faster than Chrome and in this browser, it is almost impossible today to block the UI from js. But if this were not implemented, then browsers could not give you a prompt "a script is slowing down the page, do you want to kill it?" while they do.

Comment: Hm I see but I wasn't referring to those types of long running tasks. I was referring to tasks that are longer than 60 ms for example, but not that long to get browser prompt you are mentioning (like my fibonacci example).

Comment: Am I correct to say that:
- one event loop iteration, among other things, processes one macro task, all micro tasks and optionally updates rendering (if there is rendering opportunity).
- apart from that, browser has "painting frame". If target is 60 fps, then only event loop iteration which is executed approximately around 16.67th ms, will have rendering opportunity.
- if multiple tasks were scheduled from the same execution context and one of them runs 2s, then only iteration which executes last task from the execution context will have rendering opportunity causing skipped paint frames

Comment: It's all in there: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model. It is possible that all microtasks are not processed inside the event loop, [here is a note](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#solitary-callback-microtask) saying that they may be moved to an other frame. Now, regarding "macro-task" I am not sure what it is you call like that. [The whole HTML specs use only once `macro`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahtml.spec.whatwg.org+%22macro%22), and it has nothing to do with our case.

Comment: Otherwise yes that's approximately it, except that if the browser is spinning the event loop, only "javascript tasks" get delayed (including the ones from rAF), but normally other paintings do occur (like CSS animation for instance).

Comment: By macro I mean non micro tasks

Answer (score 0):

The answer actually existed in https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model

Key points:

1. The "frame" in "A frame represents the amount of work a browser does in one event loop iteration such as processing DOM events, resizing, scrolling, rendering, CSS animations, etc" is actually an event processing iteration, i.e. all the steps of https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model
2. Your meaning of "paint frame" is the step 11 "Update the rendering" part.
3. When to create a new "paint frame" in a event iteration is determined by the browser:

   > This specification does not mandate any particular model for selecting rendering opportunities. But for example, if the browser is attempting to achieve a 60Hz refresh rate, then rendering opportunities occur at a maximum of every 60th of a second (about 16.7ms). If the browser finds that a browsing context is not able to sustain this rate, it might drop to a more sustainable 30 rendering opportunities per second for that browsing context, rather than occasionally dropping frames. Similarly, if a browsing context is not visible, the user agent might decide to drop that page to a much slower 4 rendering opportunities per second, or even less.

   So it is possible that a new "paint frame" is created after many event iteration(event/task processing).
4. For the long task, again, it is also possible that the browser decides not to create a new "paint frame".(Maybe it decides to handle these event immediately after each other or it is unnessary to create because the view content does not change).